# How to secure Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core 6 for authenticated users only?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, razor-pages

I am building a Razor Pages application, and I want to secure my pages for authenticated users only, except for the login page, and the homepage.

I was provided with an endpoint that returns a jwt token after submitting the login details. This jwt than has to be stored to authenticate any API calls that might occur later (and refreshed, by resubmitting the login details to the original endpoint).

What is the type of Authentication that I need?

I have searched [Microsoft's portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in order to try to find what type of authentication I need to add, but all of them resulted in either still allowing the protected pages, or giving an exception saying

```
No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
```

.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you want? Do you wanna unauthenticated users can't access the page you want protected?

Comment: Precisely that.

Comment: You can try asp.net core identity, Please refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).